# After insert trigger causing table lock

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a table lock problem due to trigger. In my case, I have to migrate the data from one server to another server, which needs to be done via web application. I have wrote a stored procedure to insert the data (into 9 tables) from source server/database to target server/database.

- User selects the required Employee Name and click on the Migration Button. On clicking migration button, Employee ID stores in a table (**Table A**).
- There is a trigger on this table, which used to call stored procedure.
- This stored procedure used to insert Employee data into 9 tables, based on the provided Employee ID.
- When I inserted the 10 rows to **Table A**, then Stored procedure calls for first row and wait until the accomplish of execution of stored procedure for first employee.

**Problem Facing:**

- Due to this trigger, I am unable to fetch data from those 9 table, util the accomplish of execution of stored procedure for first employee. **I need to avoid this table lock during the process.**
- Also, I want to execute all trigger in parallel, not one by one.

Please provide the some solutions to my problems.

Thanks in advance.

Sandy

Comment: How many stored procedures are involved here ? Can you show us the stored procedure and also your trigger

Comment: You can use Service Broker to make the trigger put a message in a queue. Another process (either an activated stored procedure or a job or a service, whatever works) can then read this queue and do the actual processing.

Comment: Without some details here this is just guessing. https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql

Comment: @Squirrel: There is only one stored procedure involve. I have wrote 9 different Insert into/Select statements migrate data to all 9 table (like: Workorder, Labor Hrs, Account Info, Attendance, etc.), which used to store transactional data of a employee.